# Where to add the Appcompat theme in Android Studio preview window?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-theme

Here is my problem:I have two project.One the preview have the Appcompat theme,but the other project doesn't.How could I add the AppCompat theme to that "Select Theme" window?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I restart my PC and restart Android Studio,the problem solved.Maybe it's just some files AS did not loaded.